# Why can not login if we insert the record manually into real Online Google Datastore, but can if we insert record via our system?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Ok, I got a small app, when registering a new acc, a user have to provide

```
UserName
Name
Password
```

If I register a new user via our system (Ex: Tom12, Tom, 123456), then I can login with userName **Tom12** & password: `123456`.

Now, login online Google Datastore & manually insert this record into it:
Ex: Tom13, Tom, 654321

But this time I can not login with user Name `Tom13` & password `654321`.

You can see the `getUser` function. Note that, the `userName`is also the `Key` Name

```
public static User getUser(String userName){
    Key k = KeyFactory.createKey(personKey, "User", userName);
    try {
        Entity userEntity=datastore.get(k);
        //Entity userEntity=datastore.get(userName,personKey);
        if(userEntity!=null){
            User user=new User(userName);


            setUserFromUserEntity(user, userEntity);
            return user;
        }
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

So my question is that,

*does Google Datastore add some timestamps or something like that into the system that I can not log in?*

Comment: You should include the code that handles your login process, and how you register a new user via your system

Comment: @Greg, I posted the code. It is very simple. The username is also the Use Key Name. Maybe that is the main reason?

Comment: well, you probably get an automatically generated key by doing it manually

Comment: what is `personKey`?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov, because I want to use Ancestor query, so I use personKey as a dummy key so all users are children of person so  that I can do ancestor query on Users

Comment: When you say 'cannot log in' I assume you mean you get an 'EntityNotFoundException' when trying to retrieve the entity? Also you are not showing the code that actually registers the new user and stores the entity.

Comment: Do you use same parent key when you're creating them manually? Anyways, ancestor queries doesn't work in such way, you shouldn't introduce dummy key just for this

Comment: @IgorArtamonov, that is the problem. I do not use the same parent key when creating User manually & that is the main reason? DO you know how to create parentkey on Google Datastore?

Comment: I strongly suggest to avoid using global parent key there, it's against datastore principles, you basically breaking datastore scalability by doing this